# Define header for upload file in API

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-headers, multipartform-data, api-gateway

I am trying to upload excel file to convert it to Json, but i need to passing through API Gateway. I have problem to passing the file from API Gateway.

I try to set header in `ContentDisposition`, `ContentLength` and `ContentType` manually.

```
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var Content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
        {
            var name = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);

            HttpContent content = new StringContent("");
            content.Headers.Clear();
            content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
            {
                Name = name,
                FileName = name
            };
            content.Headers.Add("Content-Length", postedFile.ContentLength.ToString());
            content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/form-data");
            Content.Add(content);
        }

        HttpResponseMessage reply = new HttpResponseMessage();
        reply = await client.GetAsync(@"http://localhost:60897/api/ExceltoJSONConversion"); 
        if (reply.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var responseString = await reply.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return Json(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseString));
        }
    }
```

I have been tried several code but `reply` always return code `405 MethodNotAllowed`.
here my controller where i proceed file

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/ExceltoJSONConversion")]
public IHttpActionResult ExceltoJSONConversion()
    {
       // Process the file from API Gateway
    }
```

Am i missing something when define Header multipart/form-data? or my code just a mess?

Answer (score 0):

Your API method accepts POST requests only ([HttpPost] attribute).

And in your client you are trying to get API through GET method (client.GetAsync ... ).

Either decorate your API method with [HttpGet] instead of [HttpPost], either change client part to use POST (client.PostAsync ... ).